# Cypher command din't wipe my deleted data

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery, wipe

I used Recuva and got a list of deleted data that can be recovered, then applied the Windows command Cypher to wipe the partitions D and C, 3 passes were made.

```
cipher /w:D:\
cipher /w:C:\
```

Finally I checked again with Recuva and discovered that the same files are still recoverable.
I want to wipe completely and definitely the deleted file, what I am missing?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  **:-)** Did you try recovering any of  those files and actually opening them?  **0:-)**  Please leave a comment @Fabby after you did...

Comment: Thank you! Yes, indeed, I could recover a file of them.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and provide the command you actually ran?

Comment: Would be interesting to know whether anyone can reproduce this. If it's reproducible, then it's definitely worrying.